# How to have individual auth users import their own calendar feed

Tags: views, feeds

I am creating a site for some local musicians, and each of them, I want to be able to import their own personal gcal as nodes.  I know that drupal has methods of doing this in the abstract - I've played around with this some:

( http://websmiths.co/blog/drupal-7-feeds-tutorials-importing-ical )

and gotten it to work on my site by just importing through the admin interface.  Basically, what I want is for the musicians to each be able to fill in a field that would have their ical/gcal information, and then on cron runs, the site updates their personal calendar of events (imported as individual nodes, displayed with views). Then I can also have a global calendar on the front page that shows all the events.

Anyone have any thoughts or advice on how to accomplish this goal?